# How to use Expression encoder using silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expression-encoder

I need to create a command-line program that accepts a `.avi` file and converts it into a `.wmv` so that I can display it using Silverlight.

Does anyone know any examples of how to convert a `.avi` file to a `.wmv`?

Answer (score 1):

use ffmpeg.exe that wil solve your purpose for converting avi to wmv via commandline

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why you would need to create a program when [Expression Encoder can do it for you using the commandline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294683.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Expression Encoder 4 comes with an SDK that includes a simple command line program called CommandEncoder. You have to build the CommandEncoder.exe using Visual Studio.

CommandEncoder.exe -m[p][d]  [Preset] [Destination]